# Aplicación no conecta con bases de datos dentro de Docker

Tags: spring-boot, docker, docker-compose, elasticsearch, neo4j

Estoy desarrollando una aplicación en Java con Spring Boot, y estoy utilizando Docker para tener Neo4j y ElasticSearch corriendo en el proyecto.

La aplicación ahora mismo es muy básica, apenas 3-4 clases, preinserción de algunos datos de prueba y poco más. **Puedo compilar el proyecto y ejecutarlo con `mvn spring-boot:run` e interactuar con las bases de datos a través de la interfaz sin problemas**: leer los datos que he pre-insertado, insertar nuevos datos, realizar búsquedas...

Ahora quiero que mi app también corra con Docker y ahí es donde comienzan mis problemas. Docker funciona, pero cuando intento correr el programa, éste falla. El error ocurre exclusivamente cuando quiero que la app corra dentro de Docker.

Si quito las inserciones (que es donde ocurren los errores, ver abajo), entonces la app arranca sin problemas, puedo ver las diferentes APIs, pero no puedo interactuar con las bases de datos. Es como si la app no encontrase las bases de datos (que antes sí encontraba).

¿Por qué puede ocurrir esto? ¿Qué puedo hacer para que todo corra en Docker?

---

El fichero docker-compose.yml de mi proyecto se ve así:

```
version: '2'
services:
  persistent:
    image: tianon/true
    restart: "no"
    depends_on:
      - neo4j
      - elasticsearch

  neo4j:
    image: docker.artifactory.aws.micompania.com/neo4j:3.2
    mem_limit: 512m
    ports:
      - 7474:7474
      - 7687:7687
    environment:
      - NEO4J_AUTH=none

  elasticsearch:
    image: "docker.elastic.co/elasticsearch/elasticsearch:5.2.2"
    mem_limit: 2048m
    ports:
      - 9200:9200
      - 9300:9300
    environment:
      - cluster.name=elasticsearch_core-dev
      - xpack.security.enabled=false
```

Y el Dockerfile:

```
FROM docker.artifactory.aws.micompania.com/neo4j:3.2

ENV NEO4J_AUTH=none

FROM openjdk:8

ADD target/miproyecto-0.0.1.jar miproyecto.jar

RUN bash -c 'touch /miproyecto.jar'

ENTRYPOINT ["java", "-Djava.security.egd=file:/dev/./urandom", "-jar",  "/miproyecto.jar"]
```

Y en el fichero application.properties tengo:

```
spring.data.neo4j.username=neo4j
spring.data.neo4j.password=neo5j

elasticsearch.clustername = elasticsearch
elasticsearch.host = localhost
elasticsearch.port = 9200
```

Arranco Docker ejecutando esto:

```
docker-compose up persistent
```

Y después de unos segundos, puedo ver que Neo4j y ElasticSearch están corriendo, yendo a las URLs `localhost:8080` y `localhost:9200`, o también con el comando `docker-compose ps`:

```
           Name                         Command             State                             Ports                           
-----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
miproyecto_elasticsearch_1   /bin/bash bin/es-docker       Up       0.0.0.0:9200->9200/tcp, 0.0.0.0:9300->9300/tcp           
miproyecto_neo4j_1           /docker-entrypoint.sh neo4j   Up       7473/tcp, 0.0.0.0:7474->7474/tcp, 0.0.0.0:7687->7687/tcp 
miproyecto_persistent_1      /true                         Exit 0
```

Después ejecuto los siguientes comandos en el *root* de mi proyecto (en este orden):

```
mvn clean install spring-boot:repackage
docker build -t miproyecto:0.0.1 .
docker run -p 8080:8080 -d miproyecto:latest
```

Entonces mi aplicación arranca (la puedo ver en docker usando el comando `docker ps`)... y se cierra a los pocos segundos al encontrarse con un error. El error en particular se debe a que la app no puede insertar los datos porque fallan las conexiones. Para Neo4j recibo un error que la conexión es rechazada:

> Caused by: org.springframework.transaction.CannotCreateTransactionException: Could not open Neo4j Session for transaction; nested exception is org.neo4j.ogm.drivers.http.request.HttpRequestException: http://localhost:7474/db/data/transaction: Connect to localhost:7474 [localhost/127.0.0.1] failed: Connection refused (Connection refused)

Y con ElasticSearch el error es un timeout:

> org.elasticsearch.transport.ConnectTransportException: [][127.0.0.1:9300] connect_timeout[30s]

Parece que el problema es que cuando la aplicación corre en Docker, es incapaz de encontrar las bases de datos (incluso cuando puedo acceder a ellas sin problemas desde el navegador).

---

Dejando de lado Neo4j por un momento, intenté cambiar la configuración en application.properties para que coincidiera con la IP interna de Docker para ElasticSearch. Pero el problema sigue igual.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

La descripción del problema cambió bastante desde que lo escribí (p.e. ya no usamos ElasticSearch, o los valores de la configuración los leemos de variables de entorno), pero al final acabamos encontrando una solución.

El error era que Spring tomaba por defecto el valor `localhost` como el servidor de Neo4J, pero en Docker, cada contenedor es *independiente* de los otros, por lo que el localhost de nuestra aplicación no era el mismo localhost de Neo4J.

La solución fue especificar el host de Neo4J en el docker-compose.yml, pero en lugar de poner "localhost", le ponemos "neo4j" (el nombre que le damos al contenedor). Algo como esto:

```
version: '2'
services:
  persistent:
    image: tianon/true
    restart: "no"
    depends_on:
      - miproyecto

  neo4j:
    image: docker.artifactory.aws.micompania.com/neo4j:3.2
    mem_limit: 512m
    ports:
      - 7474:7474
      - 7687:7687
    environment:
      - NEO4J_AUTH=none

  miproyecto:
    image: nombre-de-mi-imagen
    mem_limit: 1024m
    ports:
      - 8080:8080
    depends_on:
      - neo4j
    environment:
      - NEO4J_HOST=http://neo4j:7474
```